# Grafico em Barras com Da

Tags: r, gráfico

Estou tentando criar o um gráfico assim em R.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz toda tratativa em R para que retorne uma tabela conforme a imagem abaixo.
Mas quando faço o gráfico, ele me limita a ter eixo x e Y, sendo que no gráfico acima o eixo X tem Supervisor e Data.

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz, por onde devo começar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei isso, mas nada como podem ver, não faço a minima como colocar dois eixos x e dois eixos Y.

```
ggplot(teste,aes(x=SUPERVISOR,y=protocolos))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme_classic()+theme_light()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, vjust = .5)) 



dput(teste)

list(SUPERVISOR = c("ALEXANDRE DE HOLANDA", "ALEXANDRE DE HOLANDA", 
"ALEXANDRE DE HOLANDA", "CARINA HELENA", "CARINA HELENA", "CARINA HELENA", 
"CÁTIA MÁXIMO", "CÁTIA MÁXIMO", "CÁTIA MÁXIMO", "KELLY CHONG", 
"KELLY CHONG", "KELLY CHONG", "LUZINETE ROSARIO", "LUZINETE ROSARIO", 
"LUZINETE ROSARIO", "MICHELLY SANTANA", "MICHELLY SANTANA", "MICHELLY SANTANA", 
"PAMELA MEDEIROS", "PAMELA MEDEIROS", "PAMELA MEDEIROS"), DATA = structure(c(1563148800, 
1563235200, 1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 1563321600, 1563148800, 
1563235200, 1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 1563321600, 1563148800, 
1563235200, 1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 1563321600, 1563148800, 
1563235200, 1563321600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    totalempresa = c(4, 4, 4, 45, 45, 45, 34, 34, 34, 60, 60, 
    60, 21, 21, 21, 1, 1, 1, 57, 57, 57), protocolos = c(2, 3, 
    3, 38, 43, 43, 31, 31, 31, 57, 60, 60, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
    44, 49, 49)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(SUPERVISOR = c("ALEXANDRE DE HOLANDA", 
"CARINA HELENA", "CÁTIA MÁXIMO", "KELLY CHONG", "LUZINETE ROSARIO", 
"MICHELLY SANTANA", "PAMELA MEDEIROS"), .rows = list(1:3, 4:6, 
    7:9, 10:12, 13:15, 16:18, 19:21)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Marcus.

O Gráfico de Barras com ggplot2, talvez ajude em partes, mas acredito que não totalmente.
 COmo pode ver eu tenho uma coluna data, eu não conseguiria colocar um Fill ou algum eixo com ela?

Comment: Minha quebra no eixo X é Supervisor e Data..

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(teste)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(teste, 25))`?

Comment: Rui, coloquei na pergunta o dput(teste)